# Is it possible to connect csv file data feeds from ftp / sftp server in mongodb atlas

Tags: database, mongodb, csv, ftp, mongodb-atlas

There's an FTP server which provides CSV data feeds on a daily basis. I would like to connect my MongoDB Atlas account to this FTP server using the credentials that I've been given and have a collection created/updated whenever the data feeds are sent. The CSV files are relational, and are meant to be imported into a relational database. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I see these 2 options:

1. Create a shell script that connects to FTP and imports new data using `mongoimport` with `--drop` option (to remove stale data from Atlas).
2. Or if you want to transform source csvs and merge some tables into one Mongo collection you'll need to write a script in your favorite language (node.js/Python/etc) that will connect to to FTP, do the data wrangling and ingest it into Atlas.

Surely you can schedule these scripts to be run on a daily basis at certain time using crontab or similar.